# Configure JAVA_HOME for oozie jobs in cloudera?

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera, bigdata

I have cloudera  quickstart 5.10.0 installed in my VMware .

I want to run a oozie job which is invoking a java program to be compiled on java 1.8 but the preinstalled version of java in cloudera 5.10.0 is 1.7 .

So I downloaded `jdk1.8.0_101` and it is in `/opt/jdk1.8.0_101` .

I have changed the `JAVA_HOME` to point to `/opt/jdk1.8.0_101` in `/etc/profile` and in `/etc/default/bigtop-utils` but even then when I submit a oozie job , I can see the in logs , lib path to be `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/amd64` . So the job is failing .

[image: the oozie job logs]

Please let me know where should I exactly change the path.
Thanks in advance .

NOTE: I can't use cloudera Manager since it requires 16 GB RAM . But my desktop itself is 8 GB RAM .

Answer (score 0):

> So far it is a bit complex to upgrade jdk 1.8 in cloudera 5.10.x according to official [documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-10-x/topics/cdh_cm_upgrading_to_jdk8.html#xd_583c10bfdbd326ba-590cb1d1-149e9ca9886--7c46))

You have to locate the Java home from cloudera admin panel by following procedures:

1. Open the Cloudera Manager Admin Console.
2. In the main navigation bar, click the Hosts tab and optionally click a specific host link.
3. Click the Configuration tab.
4. Select Category > Advanced.
5. Set the Java Home Directory property to the custom location.
6. Click Save Changes.
7. Restart all services.

Detail instructions [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-10-x/topics/cm_ig_java_home_location.html#cmig_topic_16)

Comment: Thanks .   It is highly recommended that one can run Cloudera Manager in a VM with at least 10 GB of RAM.But I can't allocate that much memory in my desktop which itself holds 16 GB RAM . Can you please suggest an alternative way

Comment: They have said recommended. Not required. So you can test in your machine flawlessly. If the answer is right then don't forget mark it as right answer

Comment: I am not able to allocate more than 8 GB to  VM in VMware settings . Small correction my desktop's RAM is 8 GB .

Answer (score 0):

The above problem is resolved by doing a softlink with the following command

ln -s /opt/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/javac /usr/bin/javac .

Similarly replace javac with java and jar too.

NOTE: javac,jar and java files should be deleted inside usr/bin/ before executing the above command .